# Prove that $C(X,\mathbb R)$ has no non trivial nilpotent elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

[image]

Can anybody help me in this question. I have no idea how to proceed.
 Any **HINT** will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what nilpotent and idempotent elements are?

Comment: If $X$ is the union of two non-empty disjoint opens $U$ and $V$, we can let $f(x)=0$ if $x\in U$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x\in V$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, yes I know what are nilpotent and idempotent elements are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f \in C(X,\Bbb R)$ is nilpotent, then $f^n \equiv 0$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$. This means that $(f(x))^n = 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$, so $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$, hence $f \equiv 0$, so $f$ must be trivial.

Suppose that $X$ is disconnected with a disconnection $(U,V)$. Let $f(x) = 0$ if $x \in U$ and $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in V$. Then, $f$ is idempotent and non-trivial.

If $X$ is a connected topological space, let $f \in C(X, \Bbb R)$ be an idempotent element, i.e. $f^2 \equiv f$. Then, $f(x)(f(x) - 1) = 0$ for all $x \in X$, i.e. for all $x \in X$, $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = 1$. Take $A = f^{-1}(0)$. On one hand, $A$ is closed by continuity of $f$, and on the other hand, $A^C = f^{-1}(1)$ is closed by the same reason; this means that $A$ is clopen and so $A = \varnothing$ or $A = X$. Hence, $f \equiv 0$ or $f \equiv 1$, so $f$ is trivial.